# Fragment or Sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

A course book presents the bolded part of the below  sentence pairs as examples of fragments:

> - I am planning to go for a new smart phone. **The one I am using is dead slow.**
> - An MNC has expressed interest in recruiting our students for back office positions. **Their HR managers are expected to visit our
>     college soon.**

But my instinct is that both of them are full sentences, not fragments. They do not come within the definition of a fragment, i. e. "A [SENTENCE FRAGMENT](https://guidetogrammar.org/grammar/fragments.htm) fails to be a sentence in the sense that it cannot stand by itself. It does not contain even one  independent clause".

**Edit:**

In grammar *anaphora* is the use of a word referring back to a word used earlier in a text or conversation, to avoid repetition. In both the "sentences/fragments", there are anaphoric pronouns.

***Can the anaphoric pronouns make sentences fragments?***

***Are they actually sentence fragments?***

Answer (score 3):

Grammatically, they are not sentence fragments. They have a subject and predicate. Content-wise, they are incomplete in that they have pronouns that refer to antecedents from other sentences (in the first example, you can't know that "the one" refers to a phone reading just the bolded sentence; in the second example, reading just the bolded sentence isn't enough to know that "their" refers to the MNC), but that doesn't make them fragments in the grammatical sense.